# Solving for Lx=b and Px=b when A=LLt

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, matrix-decomposition

I am decomposing a sparse SPD matrix A using Eigen. It will either be a LLt or a LDLt deomposition (Cholesky), so we can assume the matrix will be decomposed as `A = P-1 LDLt P` where P is a permutation matrix, L is triangular lower and D diagonal (possibly identity). If I do

```
SolverClassName<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
solver.compute(A);
```

To solve `Lx=b` then is it efficient to do the following?

```
solver.matrixL().TriangularView<Lower>().solve(b)
```

Similarly, to solve `Px=b` then is it efficient to do the following?

```
solver.permutationPinv()*b
```

I would like to do this in order to compute `bt A-1 b` efficiently and stably.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look how `_solve_impl` is implemented for `SimplicialCholesky`. Essentially, you can simply write:

```
Eigen::VectorXd x = solver.permutationP()*b; // P not Pinv!
solver.matrixL().solveInPlace(x); // matrixL is already a triangularView

// depending on LLt or LDLt use either:
double res_llt = x.squaredNorm();
double res_ldlt = x.dot(solver.vectorD().asDiagonal().inverse()*x);
```

Note that you need to multiply by `P` and not `Pinv`, since the inverse of 
`A = P^-1 L D L^t P` is

```
P^-1 L^-t D^-1 L^-1 P
```

because the order of matrices reverses when taking the inverse of a product.